# cannot resolve callable context variable

Tags: django, django-templates

please take a look at the code below. I am trying to store a lambda expression in a context variable and retrieve it in my custom template tag. but the variable lookup returns an empty string instead of the lambda that I expected. why? any idea?

thanks

konstantin

`>>> c = dict(f = lambda x : 'x=%s' % x)
>>> c['f']
<function <lambda> at 0x02D7FFB0>
>>> template.Variable('f').resolve(c)
''
>>>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing lambdas to the template in Django 1.2.4 worked fine, after upgrading my code to Django 1.3, I was bit by the same issue too.  I gave up on trying to set alters_data flag and trying to apply the patch in ticket 15791 that adds a do_not_call_in_templates flag too (apparently merged in the dev version).  The way I sidestepped the problem until a proper solution is in place was to use a factory function without arguments that returned the lambda instead of passing the lambda to the template.

```
def return_a_lambda():
    return lambda x : 'x=%s' % x

c = dict(f=return_a_lambda)
>>> c['f']
<function return_l at 0x33bc668>
template.Variable('f').resolve(c)
<function <lambda> at 0x33ccaa0>
```

Django's template calls all context variables as long as they don't need an argument, hence return_a_lambda is executed and the template gets the lambda in return.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/ under "Rendering a context"

Update:
A reusable hack would be a factory function that returns a factory function:

```
def encapsulate(func):
    def wrapper():
        return func
    return wrapper
```

or a shorter version:

```
def encapsulate(func):
    return lambda: func
```

with the final code looking like this:

```
c = dict(f=encapsulate(lambda x : 'x=%s' % x))
```

which is easier to interpret.  In my case (https://github.com/rosarior/mayan) I now have to do this some 30 times aprox to get the code running in Django 1.3 :'(

Comment: thanks. this is the workaround that I used too and I mentioned it in the ticket that I referred to in my answer. I wonder why django invokes callable context variabes in the first place? I would say it is none of its business what I put in the context. :) but I guess this is a discussion for the django dev list...

Comment: Ok, I see it now, what happened to 'ejucovy' to happened to me too, using lambda as the factory function is obfuscated.

Comment: I agree with you, Changeset 16045 is making things worst by 'fixing' a problem that shouldn't exist, the template resolver should not try to call variables, that what tag and filters are for.

Answer (score 1):

here is a ticket that I found (that I have just reopened because I have found, I think, a "better" solution): https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/15791

Comment: I found that approach to be inadequate, and opened a new ticket: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/30197

Answer (score 0):

Odd, it works for me (using Django 1.3):

```
In [9]: from django import template
In [10]: c = dict(f = lambda x : 'x=%s' % x)

In [11]: c['f']
Out[11]: <function <lambda> at 0x00F9D670>

In [12]: template.Variable('f').resolve(c)
Out[12]: <function <lambda> at 0x00F9D670>
```

But out of curiosity, why use a dict instead of a django.template.context.Context?

```
In [19]: c = django.template.context.Context()

In [21]: c['f'] = lambda x: 'x=%s' % x

In [22]: template.Variable('f').resolve(c)
Out[22]: <function <lambda> at 0x01946730>
```

(I'd leave this as a comment but I don't have quite enough rep yet).

Comment: thanks. strange... I am using the trunk version. yes, the empty string is returned because my TEMPLATE_STRING_IF_INVALID was not set.

Comment: Sorry, I edited my comment a bit and removed the part about settings.TEMPLATE_STRING_IF_INVALID.

Comment: I used dict() in this sample simply because django documentation uses dict() in its example code. In real life I have Context as well.

Comment: The snippet works in the latest 1.4dev version because if do_not_call_in_templates is False (which is by default) a 'pass' statement is execute thus not trying to call the variable when resolving, on the 1.3 release however, it returns the value of TEMPLATE_STRING_IF_INVALID.  https://code.djangoproject.com/attachment/ticket/15791/do_not_call_in_templates.diff Lines 695 and 696